# Adding users to Visual Studio Online so they are on all projects

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to get Visual Studio Online to work so that when i create a new project, the same group of users are automatically able to access and contribute to the project.

No matter what I change to the Default Collection, nothing is inherited.

Is this even possible, and if so does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box.

The closest you can get would be to create a "Unber_Contributors" at the collection level and add that to "Contributers" after the team project has been created.

You could also use the API to add permissions with PowerShell and have a script that you run after the team project is created.

**However**, you are probably creating Team Projects when you should be creating Teams within a team project.

http://nakedalm.com/modelling-teams-in-team-foundation-server-2013/

You can have many applications within a single team project.

http://nakedalm.com/creating-nested-teams-visual-studio-alm/

If you have a more complicated structure you can easily create a Russian doll model and nest teams.